# Is it posible to make emmet put a space between an attribute an its value?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

When using emmet to autocomplete in VSCode, when I write for example:

```
div.class
```

It auto completes to:

```
<div class="class"></div>
```

I want to know if its possible to configure emmet on VSCode to autocomplete like this:

```
<div class = "class"></div>
```

I've found that in `settings.json` I can change some behaviour of emmet with `emmet.syntaxisProfiles`, for example when I use:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        
        "html": {

            "self_closing_tag": true,
            "attr_case": "lower"

        }

    }
```

It autocompletes tags like `br` to `<br/>` and I want to know if there is a property that can help me with the spaces between attribute and value in HTML but without creating new snippets.

Comment: Why do you want `class = "class"`

Comment: The person who teach me HTML advice me to use spaces between variables/attributes an its values to make code more legible.

Comment: I also would like to know if this advice is useful in cases like this, but I think that it might be another question

Comment: Nobody uses spaces like that, find better teachers!